# R: How do use a local csv file to create Dygraph object?

Tags: r, dygraphs

I am trying to use a local CSV data file to create a Dygraph plot in R.

It seems everywhere I look the structure is below:

```
  g = new Dygraph(document.getElementById("div"),
                  data,
                  { options });
```

So far I have below:

```
library(dygraphs)# Calling ggplot 2 library

data <- read.csv("C:/Users/test/Documents/R/R-3.3.1/R CODE/MyData2.csv", header = TRUE) # reading .csv
```

My initial thought was:

```
new Dygraph(data <- read.csv("C:/Users/test/Documents/R/R-3.3.1/R CODE/MyData2.csv", header = TRUE) # reading .csv,
            { labels: [ "series1", "series2","series3"] });
```

How can I create a Dygraph by using csv.read.

Thanks.

Comment: It seems you are mixing R and javascript code. How exactly are you trying to run this? A more complete [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) might help.

Comment: @MrFlick, it seems you are right the first part is JS. It now makes sense. Thanks for the clarification. I just want to create a digraph plot by using data from a local csv.

Comment: if you want to use R, see https://rstudio.github.io/dygraphs/